# Why does the horizontal bar size jump when resizing the chart?

Tags: chart.js

Using ChartJS 2.9.3, I've encountered a strange issue with horizontal bars shrinking as more space becomes available to the canvas. This is illustrated with the screen grabs below.

The first shows the bars in a smaller viewport area:

[image: Less space available]

The second shows the bars in a larger viewport area, where two of the bars have shrunk?

[image: More space available]

I'm not sure if this is a bug, configuration issue or expected behaviour, but I'd expect for the bars to be longer when more space is available to them. I have ruled out plugins as the cause of the issue. I have also reproduced the issue with the stock configuration (i.e. just setting the chart type). `minBarLength` does not help, actually, it also acts strangely when resizing.

Edit:

https://jsfiddle.net/27ybqt6c/

Resize the viewport, "C" is displayed wider when the viewport is small, narrower when the viewport is large.

Comment: I don't see a question here. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Really? You couldn't infer the question from the content? Not sure if you actually read it, but this is reproducible in a stock Chart JS setup.

Comment: I could infer _a_ question, but perhaps not _the_ question. You wrote "I have also reproduced the issue with the stock configuration (i.e. just setting the chart type).". Great! Then add a working snippet so we don't have to guess at your code. If you've already done the leg work and think you've found a bug then log it with the library authors.

Comment: Updated to include reproducible example

Comment: Thank you. The scale is being recalculated and you haven't started the axis at zero. That's probably the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scale is being recalculated when the chart is resized and the x-axis does not begin at zero, causing the bar to resize unexpectedly.

Setting the `beginAtZero` property to `true` will fix the issue:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  }
}
```